# how to flip y axis in imagesc of MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I have an ultrasound image, and the y axis is the depth (the top of the image will start from 0), but I don't know how to flip it.
This is my line of code:

```
imagesc(x, t(end:-1:1), x3); colormap(gray);caxis([35 80]);axis xy;
```

(t is the y axis)

[image: ultrasound image showing a y axis with 0 at the bottom and increasing upward]

Comment: You flipped the axis when you wrote "axis xy", and you flipped the numbers when you wrote `t(end:-1:1)`. I'm not sure what the issue is...

Comment: I didn't know `axis xy` existed. I would probably use [`YDir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-YDir)